# New Check Signature File in Dynamics GP

Tags: dynamics-gp, gpsignaturefile

How do I add a new signature file in Microsofts Dynamics GP.  I already have the signature scanned into a .bmp file.  What do I need to do next?

Answer (score 1):

File needs to be in .bmp format

note: on first page step one the  menu selections should be

Tools>Setup>Purchasing>MICR Payables Setup>Signature ID

(Tools was left out of the sequence)

http://www.mekorma.com/documents/058_Setting%20Up%20a%20Signature%20ID.pdf